# Transpose datatable from columns to rows based on a condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr, transpose

I have a dataset which includes data regarding the activities of different people in rows of 15 minutes. Something like this:

| Id | Ins | Out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| . | 0 | 0 |
| . | 1 | 0 |
| . | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| . | 0 | 1 |
| etc | 1 | 1 |

Here each row corresponds to a 15-minute timeslot, but the time slots referring to different people are placed beneath each other. I want to have the data in the columns "ins" and "out" to be in the same row as their respective id. So for id = 1, the whole row contains the data that is now in the columns "ins" and "out". I tried to use transpose but this obviously transposes the whole table making it very short and extremely wide.

The desired output is

| id | type | var1 | var2 | var3 | var4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ins | 1 | 0 | 1 | etc |
| 1 | out | 1 | 1 | 1 | etc |
| 2 | ins | 1 | 1 | 0 | etc |
| 2 | out | 1 | 0 | 1 | etc |

etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could

- group by `Id` to get the needed column indices with `row_number`
- pivot longer to put `Ins` and `Outs` together
- pivot wider to get the expected output

```r
data <- read.table(text = '
Id   Ins     Out
1   1   1
1   0   1
1   1   1
1   0   0
1   1   0
1   0   1
2   1   1
2   1   0
2   0   1',header=T)


library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data %>% group_by(Id) %>% 
         mutate(Var = row_number()) %>%
         pivot_longer(cols = c("Ins","Out"), names_to = 'type') %>%
         pivot_wider(names_from = Var, names_prefix = 'Var', values_from = value)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 8
#> # Groups:   Id [2]
#>      Id type   Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5  Var6
#>   <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1 Ins       1     0     1     0     1     0
#> 2     1 Out       1     1     1     0     0     1
#> 3     2 Ins       1     1     0    NA    NA    NA
#> 4     2 Out       1     0     1    NA    NA    NA
```